# Can "Add View..." in MVC.NET ignore a property when creating a strongly-typed View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can the "Add View..." wizard in ASP.NET MVC ignore a property in my Model when creating a strongly-typed View?  I select "Create" as the "View Content" in the wizard and want certain properties in my Model to be ignored.  I want to quickly create and delete Views while prototyping, and I don't want to manually edit a View that I'll only delete the next time I change my Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify existing / add new T4 templates for the visual studio code generation that is used to generate the MVC view code.

More info from [David Hayden](http://codebetter.com/blogs/david.hayden/archive/2009/01/29/overriding-global-t4-templates-in-asp-net-mvc-project-with-per-project-templates.aspx), and [the microsoft MVC team](http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2009/01/29/t4-templates-a-quick-start-guide-for-asp-net-mvc-developers.aspx)

Have fun :)